# Как написать роутинг для дочернего модуля в Angular?

Tags: typescript, angular

Помогите правильно настроить маршрутизацию в приложении на Angular
Я создал один основной компонент - public.component. В него с помощью селектора  вставляется компонент auth.component из дочернего модуля Auth.module. Как мне правильно написать роутинг для модуля auth.module, чтобы модальные окна отображались?
 [мой код](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zxzmab)

Comment: простите конечно, но такие вещи описаны в самом начале routing гайда в оф. документации 

Comment: Я не нашел там случая, когда на странице получается несколько директив router-outlet.

Comment: зачем вам именованные аутлеты?

Answer (score 0):

```
path: 'dashboard',
 loadChildren: 'app/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
```